# How do I throw an exception and scan again if the input is not bigDecimal?

Tags: java

I want to scan bigDecimal but if the input scanned is not bigdecimal it should throw an custom exception and scan it again?

I am trying the below code but not able to reach conclusion.

Code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class WrongInputException extends Exception{  
 WrongInputException(String s){  
  super(s);  
 }  
}  

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws WrongInputException
    {
        try 
        {
            int number;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             while (!sc.hasNextBigDecimal()) 
             {
                 throw new WrongInputException("Wrong data type of input....."); 
             }
             number = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(number);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Why do you throw an exception? Who is supposed to catch this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not handling the Exception you throw

You should add a try catch block to handle it inside thw while an also add a `sc.next();` to avoid the endless loop

```
 while (!sc.hasNextBigDecimal())
         {
            try {
             throw new WrongInputException("Wrong data type of input.....");

            }catch (WrongInputException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                sc.next();
            }
        }
```

Note that your try catch has no sence since you have your exception to throw

Answer (score 1):

`Sacnner#hasNextBigDecimal` does not make sense while scanning input from the keyboard. It can be used while scanning values from a file or a `Scanner` on a `String` object.

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

class WrongInputException extends Exception {
    public WrongInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws WrongInputException {
        BigDecimal number;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a BigDecimal: ");
        try {
            number = sc.nextBigDecimal();
            System.out.println(number);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WrongInputException("Wrong data type of input.....");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a BigDecimal: 1234
1234
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a BigDecimal: xyz
Exception in thread "main" WrongInputException: Wrong data type of input.....
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

**A demo of `Scanner` on a `String` object:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

class WrongInputException extends Exception {
    public WrongInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws WrongInputException {
        BigDecimal number = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("123 987654321 12.34");
        try {
            while (sc.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
                number = sc.nextBigDecimal();
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WrongInputException("Wrong data type of input.....");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
987654321
12.34
```